# Advisable to install with "UEFI-only" or "Legacy" BIOS setting on Lenovo Thinkpad?

Tags: installation, uefi

I got a new Lenovo Thinkpad. I'm preparing to install Ubuntu on the computer. The BIOS settings give me the choice of setting it to "UEFI-only" or "Legacy." I'd prefer to use UEFI-only because it's supposed to allow faster boot.  But I don't know how well Ubuntu supports UEFI. Which setting is advisable?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) supports booting from UEFI as explained by this [Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting).

> "From Ubuntu 11.04 onwards (x86_64 only), the ISO CD supports UEFI booting and the Ubuntu installer will try to setup the bootloader got (U)EFI boot."

If you are dual booting with Windows - make sure you are using Windows Vista (SP1 + 64bit) as the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

1. `If you already have an OS (eg Windows) installed in EFI mode`, you must leave your BIOS in EFI mode.
2. `If you already have an OS (eg Windows) installed in Legacy mode`, you must leave your BIOS in Legacy mode.
3. `Else, you can install Ubuntu in whatever mode you want.` You can even try both modes and check if one is faster than the other.

**Other remarks:**

- EFI is best supported by `recent 64bits (amd64 ISO) versions of Ubuntu`, such as 12.04.
- you can convert an installed Ubuntu from EFI mode to Legacy mode (or contrary) via [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s `Separate /boot/efi` option.