# Ubuntu 12.04 on Lenovo ThinkPad with UEFI

Tags: thinkpad, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop amd64 on my Lenovo ThinkPad E330.
There were no problem during installation. Now I can boot to Ubuntu and use it.

BUT: now there is only one option in Boot Devices in my ThinkPad's BIOS:

1. ubuntu

I can boot ThinkPad to Ubuntu on HDD ONLY - no other options. I switched BIOS to "Legacy devices only" - this did not help :(

Could you, please, help me and explain how to boot my ThinkPad from USB drive? How can I switch back to Legacy devices and use MBR, not UEFI?

Thank you!

Comment: You might find what you are looking for here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59176/advisable-to-install-with-uefi-only-or-legacy-bios-setting-on-lenovo-thinkpa?rq=1

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and indicate the URL that will appear.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change in BIOS settings *"fast boot"* from `enabled` to `diagnostics`.
   Keep *"Boot settings"* in `both` but `Legacy first`
2. Connect your USB stick to the usb3-port next to SD-Card reader 
   (i head frequently issues to have it recognized by the BIOS in the other port..)
3. Save BIOS settings with <kbd>F10</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> during reboot
5. You should arrive on a option frame, PRESS ENTER AGAIN to stop
   countdown. Wait 5 Seconds or so, to have all the devices recognized
   in background.
6. Now choose with <kbd>F12</kbd> *"choose temporaly startup device"*, choose something like `USB` or `flash`

NOTE: if you won't find your usb stick here, reboot and change bios settings for "Network Boot" and reboot and switch "Network Boot" again back to "Realtek.." and reboot. The Bios is behaving real strangely. Start again with No. 1.)

Good Luck, Mike

b.t.w. if you did a dual boot set-up with both, Windows and Ubuntu, check this out: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair